# How do I fix error in android studio E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: MEMBER? Register and Login Activity

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, backend

I just want the user to be able to register and login but I literally tried MS sql server, then mysql and now sqlite and I am going wrong somewhere I just do not know where. When the user enters the data it is not showed on the database. The login button is now working and when I click it I get the following error, with a bunch of other errors:
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: MEMBER
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stpapp, PID: 24359

This is my DataBaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.stpapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.*;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String MEMEBER = "MEMEBER";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_DOB = "DOB";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "Pass";



    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "stpaul.db", null, 1);
    }

    //this is called the first time I accress the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + MEMEBER + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PHONE + " INT, " + COLUMN_DOB + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT )");

    }

    // this is called if the database version number changes
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public boolean adddOne(CustomerModel customerModel){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, customerModel.getName());
        cv.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, customerModel.getEmail());
        cv.put(COLUMN_PHONE, customerModel.getPhone());
        cv.put(COLUMN_DOB, customerModel.getDOB());
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASS, customerModel.getPass());
        long insert = db.insert("MEMEBER", null, cv);

        if(insert==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Boolean checkuser(String editTextName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MEMBER where username = ?", new String[] {editTextName});
         if(cursor.getCount()>0)
             return true;
         else
             return false;
    }

    public Boolean checkpass(String editTextName, String editTextPassword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from MEMBER where username = ? and pass = ?", new String[] {editTextName, editTextPassword});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This is my register Activity class:

```
package com.example.stpapp;

        import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.StrictMode;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.*;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.sqlite.*;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText editTextName, editTextEmail, editTextPhone, editTextDateOfBirth, editTextPassword;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private TextView tvLoginOption, tvLoginLink, status;
    DataBaseHelper db;

  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

        // Initialize views
        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPhone = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        editTextDateOfBirth = findViewById(R.id.editTextDateOfBirth);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        spinnerTroop = findViewById(R.id.spinnerTroop);
        spinnerSector = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSector);
        spinnerPromise = findViewById(R.id.spinnerPromise);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);



        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String user = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String pass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                if(user.equals("") || user.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "PLease enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                CustomerModel customerModel;
                try {
                    customerModel = new CustomerModel(-1, editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextEmail.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPhone.getText().toString()), editTextDateOfBirth.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, customerModel.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Error creating customer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    customerModel = new CustomerModel(-1, "error", editTextEmail.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPhone.getText().toString()), editTextDateOfBirth.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
                }

                DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(SecondActivity.this);

                boolean success = dataBaseHelper.adddOne(customerModel);

                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Success = " + success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


  

        // Set up login link click listener
        tvLoginOption = findViewById(R.id.tvLoginOption);
        tvLoginLink = findViewById(R.id.tvLoginLink);

        tvLoginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Retrieve user input
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();
                String dateOfBirth = editTextDateOfBirth.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String selectedTroop = spinnerTroop.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String selectedSector = spinnerSector.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // Handle login link click
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is my login activity:

```
package com.example.stpapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.*;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    DataBaseHelper db;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);


        // Set up click listener for the Login button
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String user = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
                String pass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                if(user.equals("") || user.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "PLease enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Boolean checkuserpass = db.checkpass(user, pass);
                    if(checkuserpass==true) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical cause of table/column not found is due to a misunderstanding of the when the `onCreate` method is called of the class that extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Unlike an activity's `onCreate` method **the `onCreate` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and therefore the overridden `onCreate method` is called ONCE for the lifetime of the database**. The database is persistent and therefore always exists unless either the App is uninstalled (or otherwise destroyed) or if the database file is deleted (e.g. via Device Explorer).

If you simply change the executed SQL after having run the App at least once then the changes will not be applied.

If this is the cause e.g. you have changed the table name then that table would not be found.

***The quick fix, if this is the case, is to uninstall the App and then rerun the App (i.e. `OnCreate` will then be called).***

**Additional**

The following rules out an issue or issues with the definition of the table being incorrect (according to your code).

Your DataBaseHelper class otherwise appears to be usable. That is, copying the class as it is (bar commenting out the `adddOne` method rather than creating a CustomerModel class) and then using the following activity code to test the DataBaseHelper:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        Cursor csr = dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

Results in the log including:-

```
2024-01-13 13:26:50.887 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@8962cfb
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out: }
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    name=MEMEBER
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    tbl_name=MEMEBER
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE MEMEBER (ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Email TEXT, Phone INT, DOB TEXT, Pass TEXT )
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out: }
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out: 2 {
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2024-01-13 13:26:50.888 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2024-01-13 13:26:50.889 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2024-01-13 13:26:50.889 I/System.out: }
2024-01-13 13:26:50.889 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- importantly that the table **MEMBER** exists in the **`sqlite_master`** table

  - **sqlite_master** is the table in which the schema (definitions of the SQLite components exist).
  - **android_metadata** is an android specific table that is created by the SQLiteOpenHelper, it just contains the locale.
  - **sqlite_sequence** is a table automatically created and maintained by SQLite IF any columns have the AUTOINCREMENT keyword, it is used to store the  highest ever allocated rowid (a column with AUTOINCREMENT is an alias of the rowid column).

    - AUTOINCREMENT itself is misleading is not, of itself what causes an incrementing value (the rowid and therefore an alias thereof will generate a unique value, typically incrementing). AUTOINCREMENT is in fact a constraint (rule) that says that the value must be higher than any previously used value for that column in the table.
    - you may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for a more comprehensive description of AUTOINCREMENT